# Formatting the BackColor of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am relatively new to `gridviews` and I was hoping for some help on how to format the `backcolor` of a single row in a `gridview` upon the firing of the `RowDataBound` event.

Is there perhaps a good article on general formatting of `gridviews`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the event, you can do as

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
        //DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Column to check"))
        // based on that you can set the value
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
 }
```

[More about it on MSDN-formatting GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [**SelectedRowStyle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle.aspx)

```
<selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-bold="true"/>
```